# what's the euivalent of display:none; from css in the dart/flutter

Tags: css, flutter, dart

in CSS we can control the display of a class like this:

```
.class {
  display: none;
 }
```

this will behave that the element with this class is not there at all.
and to show it we just set it to

```
.class {
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

I want to know what's the way to do the same behavior in a flutter app, so I can control the display of a widget.

I am not talking about just making the widget hidden, I am talking about behaving like it's not there, so using `opacity` ways isn't a solution.

thanks

Comment: have you tried Offstage?

Comment: it's literally what I need, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visiblity is the widget you need:

```
Visibility(
  child: Text("I'm invisible"),
  visible: false,
),
```

You can also say that you don't want to show the widget, but you still want to keep the height and width of the widget.

```
Visibility(
  maintainSize: true, 
  maintainAnimation: true,
  maintainState: true,
  visible: false,
       child: Text(
      'I'm invisible',
   ),
 ),
```